# Are these ATC bricks from the 1970's LEGO?

Tags: piece-information, history, vintage

I have some Lego compatible basic bricks from early 1970s or late 1960s. Bought in Finland or maybe Germany or Sweden. Can anyone tell me more about them?

As you can see, the interlocking mechanism is different, but fits with normal Lego bricks. The colours are normal Lego white, blue, yellow, red, and black, save for one piece that is bright green.

[image]

Here's another photo where you see the logo and interlocking mechanism nearer:

[image]

Comment: Note that that particular interlocking method was also considered by LEGO as evidence by [this picture taken in the LEGO museum](http://www.flickr.com/photos/blue-moose/3907276097/in/set-72157622407019674) and presents some advantages in my opinion (if using hollow studs); it was also used by [Tente](http://www.latenteteca.com/cazando-mitos-de-tente-vs-lego/) but the larger studs make them mostly incompatible with LEGO bricks.

Comment: I've always thought ATC had to use this because LEGO patented their mechanism.

Comment: Sadly, the only ATC at that link is in the SKU, and the bottoms of those bricks looks like regular LEGO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ATC is the Asahi Toy Company from Japan. Here are the pages from their 1971 catalog showing some of their construction sets:
[image: Asahi Toy Company 1971 Toy Catalog page showing Lego-compatible sets]
[image: Asahi Toy Company 1971 Toy Catalog page showing Lego-compatible sets and parts]

Comment: Bright green 2x4 brick and blue round 2x2 exactly like in my photos. This is it.